# How to compare two jsons and return the unmatched objects using python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

The below are the sample input json files:

json1:

```
[
  {
    "App_Name": "hospital",
    "Instances": 1,
    "Memory": 256,
    "Disk_Quota": 1024
  },
  {
    "App_Name": "ecommerce",
    "Instances": 10,
    "Memory": 2048,
    "Disk_Quota": 1024
  },
  {
    "App_Name": "airlines",
    "Instances": 3,
    "Memory": 1024,
    "Disk_Quota": 1024
  }]
```

json2:

```
[
  {
    "App_Name": "bus",
    "Instances": 1,
    "Memory": 256,
    "Disk_Quota": 1024
  },
  {
    "App_Name": "hospital",
    "Instances": 10,
    "Memory": 2048,
    "Disk_Quota": 1024
  },
  {
    "App_Name": "govt",
    "Instances": 3,
    "Memory": 1024,
    "Disk_Quota": 1024
  }]
```

I need to compare two JSON files and need to return all unmatched app name objects into separate variables like

```
expected output: ================== 
unmatched objects in file = [{"App_Name": "ecommerce","Instances": 10,"Memory": 2048,"Disk_Quota": 1024},{"App_Name": "airlines","Instances": 3,"Memory": 1024,"Disk_Quota": 1024 }] 
unmatched objects in file2 = [{"App_Name": "bus","Instances": 1,"Memory": 256,"Disk_Quota": 1024},{"App_Name": "govt","Instances": 3,"Memory": 1024,"Disk_Quota": 1024}
```

Comment: What did you try? Did you get errors we can help you with? SO is a Q&A site, not a code factory.

Comment: expected output:
==================
unmatched objects in file = [{"App_Name": "ecommerce","Instances": 10,"Memory": 2048,"Disk_Quota": 1024},{"App_Name": "airlines","Instances": 3,"Memory": 1024,"Disk_Quota": 1024 }]   
unmatched objects in file2 =    [{"App_Name": "bus","Instances": 1,"Memory": 256,"Disk_Quota": 1024},{"App_Name": "govt","Instances": 3,"Memory": 1024,"Disk_Quota": 1024}]

Comment: Please include the code in your question. Unformatted code in comments is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Deserialize the each file into a list of dictionaries with [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load), restructure list of dictionaries to nested dictionaries with `App_Name` as the key. Then simply check if the keys exist in the other dictionaries with list comprehensions and filter them out.

```
from json import load

with open("json1.json") as json1, open("json2.json") as json2:
    json1dict = {d["App_Name"]: d for d in load(json1)}
    json2dict = {d["App_Name"]: d for d in load(json2)}

    unmatched1 = [v for k, v in json1dict.items() if k not in json2dict]
    print(unmatched1)

    unmatched2 = [v for k, v in json2dict.items() if k not in json1dict]
    print(unmatched2)
```

Output:

```
[{'App_Name': 'ecommerce', 'Instances': 10, 'Memory': 2048, 'Disk_Quota': 1024}, {'App_Name': 'airlines', 'Instances': 3, 'Memory': 1024, 'Disk_Quota': 1024}]
[{'App_Name': 'bus', 'Instances': 1, 'Memory': 256, 'Disk_Quota': 1024}, {'App_Name': 'govt', 'Instances': 3, 'Memory': 1024, 'Disk_Quota': 1024}]
```